Optimizing the query for removing duplicate rows based on another column constraint
I have a table in SQL Server which has some columns and some of them are called ElementID1 and FrameLossCount etc. I want to write a query that search for duplicates in ElementID1. The instructions should be in a way that all values in ElementID1 be checked and in case of being repeated more than once the FrameLossCount values be checked and only the greatest be kept and other rows with the exact same ElementID1 get removed.
I came up with this code, but I want to check whether an easier code exists (due to some restrictions another shorter code) Thanks.
WITH RankedDuplicates AS (
    SELECT 
        ElementID1,
        FrameLossCount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ElementID1 ORDER BY FrameLossCount DESC) AS rn
    FROM 
        TableName
)
DELETE FROM TableName
WHERE ElementID1 IN (
    SELECT ElementID1
    FROM RankedDuplicates
    WHERE rn > 1
);

I tried it and I need a shorter and clearer query.

Why do you need a shorter more concise query? That seems pretty clear to me.

Mysql is very different to sql server, please correct your tags

You can probably delete directly from your CTE without needing to use it in a sub-query

Hmm. the published query will delete all elementid1 where there are duplicates..which is not what I think you want.

True, I missed something super important, and that is the Date. I only have to check duplicates of every single date

To expand on DaleK's answer, see this db<>fiddle.

@user2019455 - If you need to reset for each date, you can probably just expand the PARTITION BY to something like PARTITION BY ElementID1, CAST(datetimeColumn AS DATE).

You can just do: with RankedDuplicates (...) delete RankedDuplicates where rn > 1 no need for second join (probably), also, what's with the CTEs, it's more concise to just write the subquery

Assuming your date columns declared as datetime, you can use following queries:
Query1 with CTE: (dbFiddle1)
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ElementID1, DATE ORDER BY FrameLossCount DESC) AS rn
    FROM 
        yourTableName
)
DELETE FROM cte 
WHERE rn > 1;

Query2 with Joins & Subquery (dbFiddle2
delete TableName from yourTableName t1
left join
(select max(FrameLossCount) maxFrameLossCount,ElementID1, DATE
    from yourTableName
    group by ElementID1, DATE
) t2
on t1.ElementID1 = t2.ElementID1 and
    t1.date = t2.date and
    t1.FrameLossCount = t2.maxFrameLossCount
where t2.maxFrameLossCount is null


how about adding another snippet at the end which removes duplicates as well?

@user2019455 both queries do remove duplicates? What do you actually mean?

Above queries itself contain Delete statment that removes duplicates.

I meant maybe two ( or more) records at least with two same exact values exist

@user2019455 yip that's the definition of removing duplicates, are you suggesting the queries provided don't work? Might be time to provide a [mre] because you question is getting less clear as time goes on

I'm looking for the shortest possible query which ensures that now duplicate rows in that table exists.

@user2019455 why? Does the number of characters you need to type really make a difference here?
